Probability of not having a draw
Problem
In a given race the probability of winning of four horses $A, B, C, D$ are $1/4$, $1/5$, $1/6$,$1/7$ respectively. Assuming that, a dead heat (a draw) is impossible, find the chance that one of them wins the race.
I solved this question by two approaches, both giving different answers.
Approach 1
Let $ P(A) $, $ P(B) $, $ P(C) $, and $ P(D) $ be the probabilities of winning of the horses $ A $, $ B $, $ C $, and $ D $ respectively. Then:
$$ P(A) = \frac{1}{4}, \quad P(B) = \frac{1}{5}, \quad P(C) = \frac{1}{6}, \quad P(D) = \frac{1}{7}. $$
Since the above events are mutually exclusive, the chance that one of them wins is:
$$ P(A \cup B \cup C \cup D) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D) $$
Calculating this:
$$ = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} = \frac{319}{420}. $$
Approach 2
For $A$ to win the race, rest of the horses must lose. Let $P_1$ be the probability for the occurrence of this event.
$$P_1 = \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{6}{7}$$
Similarly
$$P_2= \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{6}{7}$$
$$P_3 = \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{6}{7}$$
$$P_4 = \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{7}$$
Therefore, probability that any one horse wins the race is
$$ \sum P_i = \frac{57}{140}$$
Why is there a difference in answers? And which approach is correct?
EDIT I've changed the notation from $a:b$ to $a/b$. $a:b$ created confusion as it mostly represents odds not probability. Sorry for the  confusion!

Those are odds not probabilities

Odds of $1:1$, say,  would mean a probability of $\frac 12$.

You wrote in another comment, "The original question did infact use odds. I've already translated the odds to probabilities while framing the question." What did the original question say about the odds before you translated them to probabilities? Did it say $1:3$ for horse A, which you translated to $1:4$? If so, for an English-language site, write $1/4$ for the probability and you will be understood correctly.

@DavidK sorry for the misunderstanding. should i edit it then?

That could be helpful.

Neither calculation is correct,  as you were given odds, not probabilities.  Odds of $a:b$ are the same as a probability of $\frac a{a+b}$.
And your header is not correct,  since we are given that the probability of a draw is $0$. You mean to ask for the probability that one of the named horses will win
Once you translate the odds to probabilities,  the logic of the first approach is correct.
The second approach does not make sense.  The various events are not independent and,  in any case, you ignore the other horses in the race. We know there must be other horses, as your probabilities do not sum to $1$.
Note: since a (rather silly) pseudo controversy has arisen in tne comments, I feel I ought to be clear.  Using, say, $1:4$ as a notation for $\frac 14$ is bizarre. Especially when ordinary fractional notation is freely used.  Please do not ever do that.  And when we are in the context of gambling, horse races say, then $1:4$ unambiguously denotes odds, not probability.  These rules are not complex.  Let's all just stick to them.

The original question did infact use odds. I've already translated the odds to probabilities while framing the question.

You wrote out odds, not probabilities.  $1:4$ is not a notation used for a probability of a fourth.

@lulu Division uses the operators /, : and ÷ in text. Odds and probabilities are both numbers, just that probabilities is fraction of cases to all cases while odds are ratios of cases to other cases. So this answer mostly points out an incorrect assumption about the meaning of :.

@Lazy  in a random context, maybe.  But...well, the OP is talking about horse races.  There's already a lot of confusion about odds and probability especially as pertains to sports and gambling...insisting on using the same notation for both of them just makes it worse.

@lulu This is a site about mathematics, not about horse races. The question clearly states that these are probabilities, not odds, so this should be enough to avoid confusion in a community who knows about maths. You are basically saying: I do not accept this operator commonly used for divisions as anything different than odds. But insisting on you own definitions does not make your point correct.

@Lazy  I disagree.  Nobody interprets Horse $A$ will win at $1:4$ as a probability.  But, no matter.  You are entitled to your opinion.  I will not comment further on the subject.

@lulu Luckily it literally says the probability is ... so there is no room for interpretation. My opinion does not matter, what matters it that your statement is objectively false.

@Lazy: The trouble is, a probability can be expressed as odds, and vice versa. In this particular case I think both interpretations are reasonable.

@psmears No. A probabilty is a probabilty, odds are odds. You can calculate one from the other. But that does not mean they’re the same. It is like saying: Meters and inches can be calculated from each other, so if you read 1m it is reasonable to assume they meant 1in.

@Lazy: I didn't say they were the same thing. But just as you can express the mileage of a car in kilometres, you can express a probability by giving odds (and vice versa). Sometimes when the notation is ambiguous you need to use context to know which is intended; here there are strong signals for both - which explains why some people (you) are convinced it's one, and some (lulu, David K) are convinced it's the other. I don't think either view is unreasonable.

Good Lord. Please keep this nonsense elsewhere.  Notation is notation.  And context is context,  $1:4$ is a bizarre notation for $\frac 14$ in any context .  And it is a strictly unacceptable notation in the context of gambling where $1:4$ unambiguously denotes odds.  There is no mathematical question here.

@lulu Good, then as you seem to think that this is in fact a non-mathematical question, why to you answer it instead of voting to close it for being off topic?

@psmears But you are claiming ambiguity when the question clearly states that they are probabilities. So if I say 1 in the unit of meters it does not make sense to assume they are inches, and if I say a probability of 1 : 4 it does not make sense to assume they are odds (1 : 4 as odd reads as 1 to 4 while 1 : 4 as probability reads as 1 in 4, both of which are valid uses of ratios by the way). I am not saying that this is the best way to notate things. I’m just saying that lulu and DavidK insisting that things are odds just because they’re given as ratios is incorrect.

It is like drawing one ball from a urn which contains balls of $5$ different colors: $A, B, C, D$ and $E$.
Here
$$P(A)=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$P(B)=\frac{1}{5}$$
$$P(C)=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$P(D)=\frac{1}{7}$$
$$P(E)=1-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}=\frac{101}{420}$$
We draw only one ball from the urn. (So there is no dead heat.) The probability of drawing one of A, B, C, D is obviously $$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D).$$
There is $\color{red}{only \; one}$ game, $\color{red}{not \; four}$.
Thus in considering $P(A)$, there is no need to consider $P(B), P(C)$ and $P(D)$.
$\mathbf{Approach \; 1}$ is correct.

The figures $1:4$ are odds, which correspond to a probability $1/5$ rather than $1/4$. Other than that, this is fine.

@DavidK No, they aren’t. 1 : 4 = 1 / 4 = 1 ÷ 4 in in-text typography. In fact odds an probabilities are both just numbers.

@Lazy Good point, and it does say "probabilities" in the question. But in in-text typography, conventionally, probabilities are written with a slanted line, as you did with $1/4$, while odds are written with a colon. And although both are numbers (or can be converted to numbers), they are not interpreted identically. You can have odds of $3:2$ but not a probability of $3/2$. If $1:4$ was actually intended to mean $1/4$ probability, the question was poorly written.

@DavidK That is incorrect. It is true that odds are often written as fraction separated by :. By the way in betting they are often written with a -. But that does not mean that probabilities are typically written with /. The / simply denotes a division, and you might be used to seeing / for division, but some people are not. The OP clearly is used to using : for division. That does not make his notation wrong. I at least have never found a definition stating that if a fraction denotes a probability it has to be notated with a /.

@Lazy I suppose you think Wikipedia has it wrong too.

@DavidK No? I’m not saying that using : for odds is wrong, I’m saying that insisting something is an odd just because : was used is nonsensical. Or if you want to play the wikipedia game: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Notation clearly states that : is used for division in some countries, while in English speaking countries this usage is exclusive to ratios (as also explicitely stated in ISO 80000-2). So saying: the probability is 1 : 4 is correct, in the sense that 1 : 4 is either a division, or a ratio between incidence to total.

@Lazy Use of a colon for division would be a translation error under that interpretation, since this is an English-language site. Perhaps that's what happened. The person who wrote the question has not been clear on this point. I have asked for clarification.
